# What might be screwing up my display?

Tags: graphics, 14.10, intel-graphics

I have recently installed Ubunutu 14.10. For some time of usage after booting up, the graphics is fine but after some time it gets screwed up (specially the fonts)[See attached image]. I am not able to determine what is going wrong. Can sometime tell me how can I troubleshoot this problem? My laptop is HP-Probook 4410s with Intel Mobile Graphics card.

**UPDATE:** A hint can be taken from the fact that no such distortion is observed within Google Chrome window. The graphical distortion happens in all other windows. This rules out the possibility of some hardware problem. Is there some problem with the Window Manager?

[image]

Comment: Graphics in Google Chrome browser seems to be working fine so I don't think it is a hardware issue.

Comment: what is the output of `grep AccelMethod /var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run applications which use different graphic libraries (GTK, wxWidgets, QT, pure X11) Maybe you will notice that some apps get distorted fonts while other do not, and find out which library should be updated/reinstalled.